# How to transfer the activity and fragment information to the server with a button in the activity?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity that contains several edit texts and a view pager
And inside the view pager there are some text edits

Now, I want when the user fills the form inside the activity and the form inside the fragment, all the information will be transferred to the server by pr[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNN34.jpg)essing one button.

The problem is that the button is in the main activity and I don't have access to edit the texts inside the fragment

What should I do ???

Answer (score 1):

As your `Activity` is in control of the `Fragment`, you could just implement a custom method inside the `Fragment` like `fun getFormInput(): Map<String, String>` or similar.

When the "send" button is clicked, you use that method to receive all information from the `Fragment`.

Alternatively, you could implement a custom listener, with the [observer pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern), to be notified inside the `Activity` on every change of a form field in the `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an interface that will return you the map object as mentioned above.

Create a method in the interface that returns the data stored in all the dit texts in any Data Structure that best fits your use case.

In your fragment - add a watcher to all your edit texts and send the values present in the edittexts to the activity using the method in the interface.